# How to highlight all Sundays in crystal reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Dear I am creating an attendance project so I want to highlight all Sundays in crystal report. I have one more problem that i want to view group values not details section field only group values in horizontal. I know details section can be view horizontally.It is a win form c# project.

my screen shot is not being uploaded. there is no upload and save button after selecting pic.

Comment: Show us the report design plz

Comment: I said i am creating an attendance report in which dates come horizontally on top and i have grouped dates so i want to make it horizontally. and also want to highlight all Sundays of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click in your field placed on the report, then choose the `Highlighting Expert`.
Then Click the `New Button`.

Choose your field, then from the right panel, select `is equals to` and write `Sunday`. After that select the appropriate font color or the background color as you wish. Then select `OK`.

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: thanx zeina it worked.